# Machine Learning - AdaBoost the best standalone algorithm

Tags: machine-learning, decision-tree, knn, adaboost

On a given problem, I've checked using k-fold (k=10) a few standalone algorithms among them are CART and KNN.

KNN came with the upper hand over CART and I furthermore tuned it using the best k I found (3).

When I went on to check ensemble methods I tried AdaBoost with the tuned KNN and the default CART and surprisingly the CART performed better.

I'm not so deep to the math behind the scenes but I don't really understand how this makes sense.

So two questions:

1. How come AdaBoost with CART performed better than the tuned KNN?
2. If standalone performance does not predict ensemble base estimator, how do I wisely choose base estimators for ensemble methods?

Comment: Welcome to the world of **nonlinearity**. I'm afraid the question is way too broad for SO. I recommend to read some introduction to Machine-learning  which will help to understand these kind of behaviours. Wisely choosing base-estimators is also heavily done empirically.